# В чем отличие в присвоении атрибута класса в конструкторе и нет

Tags: python, ооп

```
class W:
    a = 1
```

или

```
class W():
  def __init__(self):
    self.a = 1
```

В чем отличие? И какие фишки есть с каждым вариантом?

Comment: Схожий [вопрос](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8959097/what-is-the-difference-between-class-and-instance-variables-in-python) на enSO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В первом случае переменная a является атрибутом класса, и доступна и как W.a и как:

```
w = W()
w.a
```

Во втором же случае переменная создаётся в момент инициализации объекта, а значит принадлежит объекту и доступна только как:

```
w = W()
w.a
```

Основная разница заключается в том, как распределяется память. В первом случае память на хранение данной переменной выделяется при объявлении класса, во втором же случае память выделяется для каждого из объектов класса. Используется и то и другое, всё зависит от задачи.

Из фишек - можно например изменять значение сразу для всех объектов класса:

```
class A():
    b = 1
a = A()
b = A()

a.b # результат 1
b.b # результат 1
# Когда меняем значение для члена класса
A.b = 5
# Оно изменяется для всех объектов класса
b.b # результат 5
a.b # результат 5
```

Comment: Очень подробно! Все яснопонятно! Спасибо вам!

Answer (score 1):

Немного расширю ваш пример:

```
class T:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 10
        self.b = [1, 2, 3]

    c = 20
    d = [15]
```

Когда интерпретатор встречает этот код, он [выполняет тело класса](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#class-definitions) и все локальные переменные сохраняет как атрибуты этого класса.

Таким образом, мы имеем класс `T`, у которого есть три атрибута (не считая автоматические): `c`, `d` и `__init__` ([объявление функции тоже создаёт локальную переменную](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/executionmodel.html#binding-of-names)!):

```
>>> T.__dict__
{
    '__init__': <function T.__init__ at 0xXXX>,
    'c': 15,
    'd': [20],
    # ...
}
```

Когда мы создаём экземпляр класса, выполняется метод `__init__` класса, в который передаётся заготовка создаваемого экземпляра. Таким образом, в строке

```
t = T()
```

Мы получаем экземпляр `t` класса `T`, который имеет два атрибута: `a` и `b`:

```
>>> t.__dict__
{
    'a': 10, 
    'b': [1, 2, 3]
}
```

Что происходит дальше, когда мы пытаемся получить доступ к атрибутам?

Например, имеем три строки кода:

```
print(t.a)    # 10
print(t.c)    # 20
print(T.c)    # 20
# print(T.a)  # error: у класса нет такого атрибута
```

В первой строке интерпретатор посмотрит в атрибуты переменной `t`, найдёт среди них имя `a` и вернёт его значение.

Во второй строке происходит следующее. Интерпретатор не может найти атрибут `c` среди атрибутов объекта `t`, поэтому обращается к объекту класса, экземпляром которого является этот объект. У класса уже имеется нужный атрибут, поэтому на этом поиск завершается, возвращается значение `20`.

Третья строка выполняется аналогично первой, с условием что атрибут ищется сразу у класса.

Четвёртая строка выполнится с ошибкой, потому что атрибуты экземпляров не распространяются на классы.

---

Какие за счёт этого возникают эффекты?

Все атрибуты класса доступны всем экземплярам. Мы можем изменять атрибуты или заменять их значения, и это отразится на всех экземплярах класса:

```
t1 = T()
t2 = T()

print(t1.d, t2.d)  # [15] [15]
# изменим атрибут класса, пользуясь тем, что список является изменяемым типом
t1.d.append(16)
print(t1.d, t2.d)  # [15, 16] [15, 16]

# создадим новый атрибут уровня класса
T.x = "Hello!" 
print(t1.x, t2.x)  # Hello! Hello!
```

Важно помнить, что атрибуты экземпляра класса скрывают атрибуты класса:

```
t1.d = [-1, -2]
print(t1.d, t2.d, T.d)  # [-1, -2] [15, 16] [15, 16]
```

Т.е. в строке `t1.d = [-1, -2]` не изменяется значение атрибута класса, а создаётся новый атрибут у объекта `t1`. Поэтому изменить значение неизменяемого атрибута класса через экземпляр этого класса не получится. Если требуется подобная операция, стоит изменять атрибут класса.

---

В итоге имеем следующее: при использовании атрибутов класса стоит проявлять **осторожность с изменяемыми объектами** (изменение в одном экземпляре затронет все остальные), а также со **скрытием атрибутов класса** атрибутами экземпляра класса.

С учётом этих замечаний обычно рекомендуется создавать все атрибуты в методе `__init__` класса, а не в самом классе.

Иногда в самом классе хранят константные значения, относящиеся ко всем экземплярам, например, значения по умолчанию.